# 400 Bad Request From users/show.json twitter request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter

I'm using Twitter OAuth provider to login to my site.  This works great; I can login, and get the access token.  I want to make an additional request to the server to grab some user information.  Using the 1.1 API, I do:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=name");
var response = request.GetResponse(); //400 bad request error
```

Again, I've successfully logged in, and at this point, I have not made any successful requests, so I'm not being rate limited.  Any idea what my problem is?

I can make the previous API work fine, using the URL: `http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=name`.  But not the new URL.

Thanks.

Comment: This error looks familiar. service is not reachable, possible reasons can be url is not formed properly or there is no method defined for the request or method might be a post request and you are using post or vice versa. Not sure though.

Comment: I basically took the sample URL from the Twitter API documentation, and replaced the screen name with a correct screen name, and no go on the V 1.1 API, but works great on the V 1 API.

Comment: I think you would have to ask twitter team here. Because with the information you have shared, it can be deduced that the service is at fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Twitter Developers Documentation for response codes](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses), you get a 400 in this case :

> The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain
>   why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate
>   limiting. In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered
>   invalid and you will get this response.

Seeing your code (your URL is right and you use the 1.1 version of the API) I think that you forgot to [authorize the request](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request).

Comment: I'm using MVC 4's twitter provider to authorize the user; this approach is working for Facebook; I'm surprised that it wouldn't be working here....  do you have to pass the access token along with the request?

Comment: @BrianMains: Yes. All what you have to do for authenticating requests is explained here : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request . The access token is the `oauth_token` parameter.

Comment: I see what you mean, yes I think that is my problem.  I will try that out.